# How do I get iTunes to play all music from a specific year?

Tags: itunes

How do I select and then play all songs from release year?  e.g. Play all music from 1969.  Even better, play all rock genre music from 1969.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Smart Playlist. These are playlists that are dynamic and can be built off filters on track metadata.

To create a new Smart Playlist select `File > New > Smart Playlist...` (or Opt-Cmd-N) and then set the following options to build a Smart Playlist that always contains all the tracks that are from 1969 in your library:

[image: A Smart Playlist for 1969]

If you wanted to limit it to a specific *genre* from 1696 press the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add another filter criteria and pick a genre like so:

[image: A Smart Playlist for Rock from 1969]

You can filter in all kinds of ways -- Smart Playlists are incredibly powerful.

Comment: Thank you Ian!!  That is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  And I like the fact I can exclude genres (e.g. "Holiday" and "New Age") when I want to listen to Rock, etc. from 1969!  This is perfect!

Comment: @newawryzen no problem. If this answer solves your problem there's a green checkmark right below to the up and down vote buttons -- just press the checkmark to "accept" this as the correct answer so anyone else who happens upon this problem in the future knows that this is what solved it for you. Thanks!